# Sitecore9.0.1 Error Code:ERROR_DACFX_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER. SqlSysClrTypes(x64) ,SqlDom(x64) is missing in default location which I was installed

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

**I am trying to install Sitecore 9.0.1 but I got below error**

```
[---------------------------------------------- InstallWDP : WebDeploy -----------------------------------------------]
[WebDeploy]:[Path] C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe
Error Code: ERROR_DACFX_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER
More Information: The SQL provider cannot run with dacpac option because of a missing dependency. Please make sure that DacFx is installed.  Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DACFX_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER.
Error count: 1.
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero 
[TIME] 00:00:12
exit code - (-1)
At C:\Sitecore\SIFLess\SIFless-EZ-1699959091.ps1:42 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
 
Transcript stopped, output file is C:\Sitecore\SIFLess\xconnect-xp0.231114 (7).log
Invoke-CommandTask : Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code - 
(-1)
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.1.0\Public\Tasks\Invoke-WebDeployTask.ps1:36 
char:2

+     Invoke-CommandTask -Path $Path -Arguments $msdeployArgs -TaskName ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-CommandTask
```

I have Installed `Microsoft SQL Server Data-Tier Application Framework"x64 and x86  Version(13.0.3370.2)`
and also I installed `Microsoft system clr type for sql server 2016 [ENU\x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi and ENU\x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi] Version 13.0.1601.5, microsoft.sqlserver.Transactsql.ScriptDom [ENU\x64\SqlDom.msi and ENU\x86\SqlDom.msi]`

And then I updated the registry:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy\3

DacFxPath :
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll

DaxFxDependenciesPath :
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\

[image: Registry]

I found one thing that `SqlSysClrTypes(x64)` and `SqlDom(x64)` is missing in the default location `[C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin OR C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\SDK\Assemblies]` which I was installed.

SqlSysClrTypes(x86) and SqlDom(x86) are stored under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\SDK\Assemblies`